# Какие слова можно убрать из предложения без потери смысла?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Хочу разработать приложение, которое на вход получает текст (к примеру, вопрос с этого сайта), а на выход отдает набор слов, описывающий его (на данный момент, это набор слов в нормальной форме и их частота).

Спешу предположить, чтобы иметь некое «представление о предложении», не обязательно учитывать все слова, к примеру, вероятно, можно откинуть предлоги, без существенного изменения «представления». Было бы крайне интересно узнать, какие именно слова можно не учитывать с позиции лингвистики?

**Обновление**

"Набор, описывающий его" – это массив слов, встречающихся в предложении в нормальной форме, и их частота. То есть для предложения "По реке плывет корабль, по которому идут люди", это будет:

- по: 2
- река: 1
- плыть: 1
- корабль: 1
- который: 1
- идти: 1
- люди: 1

Этот список является "описанием" предложения. То есть если сравнить этот список с каким–либо с подобным список любого другого предложения, мы узнаем, на сколько они похожи. (*Поиск похожих предложений моя основная цель.* Если я делаю это не верно, пожалуйста, подскажите, как это делать правильно.)

**Обновление 2**

Конечная цель: по имеющемуся большому тексту определять принадлежит ли новое предложение к этому тексту, либо оно совсем о другому. Например, на основе большого количества вопросов по грамматике русского языка на этом сайте определить, является ли случайное предложение вопросом по грамматике.

Comment: А что такое "набор, описывающий его"? Что за "описание" такое? "Представление о предложении" - тоже ни смысла, ни понимания не добавляет. Всё зависит от глубины понимания и проникновения и - самое главное - от предназначения такого "описания". Скажем, грамматический разбор - одно, семантика - совсем другое...

Comment: А цель сей операции?

Comment: @Niemand Обновил вопрос.

Comment: .*Конечная цель* - теперь понятнее, но задача нерешабельная. Процентов 30 ошибки я вам гарантирую при таком методе при  самом лучшем "наборе". Реально - больше, контекст рулит всегда. Я попробую, конечно, обосновать в ответе (чуть позже, как посвободнее буду), но к идее отношусь заведомо скептически.